# I want to display only tax it wont be include in grand total

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, tax

I want to display subtotal after subtracting and i don't want to add that tax in to grand total .
Now, i have a product price with including tax.
I tried the solution from `system-> configuration-> tax` but its not giving me the result as expected

Comment: Welcome to Magento. Have you created tax rules and have you applied to products?

Comment: Yes I applied on product actually the scenario was I have the prices with including tax and I don't want to display the  excluding tax prices but I want to display the tax

Comment: You mean, tax applied on products at checkout but included in grand total now right?

Comment: No I have a price of product with including tax and I want to apply the tax process as backward

Comment: ok. create new tax rules from admin-->sales-->tax-->manage tax rules-->create new rule

Comment: Hello Thanks for your help i got the solution thank u very much for your help

Comment: i am glad to listen this from you. you are welcome. i will post answer please upvote and accept bro. Best of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please check whether the tax rules created or not in admin panel. 
   If not,
2. Login to admin panel and Go to admin-->sales-->tax-->manage tax rules-->create new rule here
3. Assign the tax classes to the product when the product creation time.
4. Set the changes here at `system-> configuration-> tax`
5. Re-index the data and check the tax is applying or not.